# teb_local_planner problems

Tags: ros2, colcon, teb-local-planner, ros-foxy

I use ROS2 Foxy and I'd like to Colcon build but it's can't the problem make my com not responding. I try to check with this command

> > rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y
> > then it return
> > ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
> > to system dependencies:
> > teb_local_planner: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libg2o]

but I already installed with

> > sudo apt install ros-foxy-libg2o
> > but still return the same error.

How should I do for build this workspace ,Thank a lot who give me comment and solution I'm just start with ROS.